# Custom registration form page/template

Tags: user-registration

I am trying to create a registration page on my site to allow visitors to register on the site and have access to special contents.

- I installed Cimy User Extra Fields to add extra fields to `wp-signup.php`
- In my registration page I make an Ajax call to `wp-signup.php` to grab the form and style it.

The problem is that if registration fails (e.g. use an existing email in database), you are  redirected to the default WordPress registration page, with the WordPress template...

Is there a way to create a page for registration with extra-fields with a custom template?

I've also tried using the Simplr User Registration Form plugin but is not working...

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look on [Profile Builder Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/), that allows you to customize your website by adding a front-end menu for all your users, giving them a more flexible way to modify their user profile or register new users (front-end user registration). You can add custom fields to  your registration form and customize the redirect page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at pie-register http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pie-register/
It allows adding custom fields to the registration form.

A great tool for frontend log-in and registration is theme-my-login
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue on an un-released site and used a combination of 2 plugins.

I used the [user meta pro plugin](http://user-meta.com/) for front end registration and login. It's a cheap plugin for a premium ($19 I think).  The free version might even handle it.

Then the [redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted the long article about how to create Sign Up page on WordPress site (basically on Multisite but similar methods can be used on default WP install). Right now article on russian language: [How to replace default wp-signup.php](https://korobochkin.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/rukovodstvo-po-sozdaniju-stranicy-registracii-v-multisajte/) But I also publish my source code and few screenshots.

My article allows you create custom register page without any plugins and using only clean WordPress techniques. No hacky or dirty solutions like change wp-signup.php directly in WordPress root folder, JS code not worked with disabled Java Script in browsers or Apache redirects and more.

Also [similar question and long discussion](https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/user-registration-on-multisite/) available at bbpress support forum and we talked there on english.